# Resizable selection area on realtime video

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation

I want to develop an iOS App which will be grab an specific text from a paper using resizable selection area on Real Time video.[Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPkJ6HrCvyc) to see the link of an app which have similar feature. Can you please tell me the which API or Code should i implement in order to add similar features in iOS Platform. I will highly appreciate valuable resource links or project links or Code Sample.